# При обновлении textBox меняется его содержимое

Tags: массивы, winforms, textbox

Добрый день.Столкнулся с такой проблемой.На форме создано два `textBox`,в первый вводится текст,а затем по определенному алгоритму выбираются слова из первого `textBox` и посредством `AppendText` заносятся во второй `textBox` - другими словами идет перестановка слов текста.Так вот.Когда я обновляю второй `textBox` (в котором отражены переставленные слова из первого) перестановка исчезает и отображается полная копия первого `textBox`.Когда я создаю массив из слов второго `textBox` через `Split()`,то оказывается,что индексы элементов массива не соответствуют расположению слов во втором `textBox`,но зато соответствуют расположению слов в первом `textBox`.Очень нужна помощь,как создать массив из второго `textBox`,чтобы он соответствовал РЕАЛЬНОМУ расположению слов во втором `textBox`

Comment: Составьте [минимальный пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и добавьте метку языка программирования. Попробуйте продемонстрировать проблему на примере: какие вводятся строки, какой получается результат.

Comment: можно и нужно было бы  добавить код а не сказку читать